# How to load additional jar in the eclipse plugin ClassLoader

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a eclipse plugin and I am willing to use JavaFx in Eclipse `org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart` to create a editor panel.

It seems I have to override method `void createPartControl(Composite composite)`, `javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas` is the bridge of `Composite` and JavaFx `Sence`(as shown in the document http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm). But `javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas` is in "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar" which is not a default loaded component by JVM or Eclipse.

How can I make eclipse load "jfxswt.jar" and my plugin at same time(same `ClassLoader`) at runtime? Or is there another way to do make it work?

Comment: There is a discussion of this on the Eclipse forums [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/796180/)

Answer (score 0):

Place jar in lib folder of project and add this jar to build path. It would be automatically accessible to the project and running eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add all required jars in 'plugins' folder of eclipse and right click on your project, Remove and Again add runtime plugin dependency, it will add all jars needed by project.